# cakePHP + extjs row editor and REST

Tags: rest, cakephp, extjs

I've implemented REST routing in cakePHP to properly route REST style requests to the proper methods in my controller.

This is what I've added to my routes.php

```
Router::mapResources(array('object_fields'));
```

This properly routes the REST requests to my index/add/edit/delete methods inside my controller.

In my EXTJS grid I am using the row editor with a restful store to achieve CRUD behavior.

Here is the code for my grid

```
myapp.object_field_grid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
  closable: true,
    stripeRows: true,

    frame: true,
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    editor: new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor({
     saveText: 'Update',

     }),

    onAdd : function(btn, ev){
     var u = new this.store.recordType({
      name : '',
      type: '',
     });

     this.editor.stopEditing();
             this.store.insert(0, u);
             this.editor.startEditing(0);


  },

  onDelete : function(){
  },

  initComponent: function() {

   var proxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
   url: 'object_fields/',


   });

   var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({

   totalProperty: 'totalCount',
   successProperty: 'success',
   idProperty: 'id',
   root: 'data',
   messageProperty: 'message'  
   }, [
       {name: 'id'},
        {name: 'name', allowBlank: false},
       {name: 'type', allowBlank: false},
   ]);


   var writer = new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
      encode: false,

   });

   var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    baseParams: {id: this.object_id},
    id: 'object_fields',
       restful: true,     
       proxy: proxy,
       reader: reader,
         writer: writer,
       });

   store.load();

   var object_field_columns =  [
     //  {header: "id", width: 250, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'id', editor: new      Ext.form.TextField({})},                         
       {header: "name", width: 250, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'name', editor: new     Ext.form.TextField({})},
      {header: "type", width: 250, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'type', editor: new    Ext.form.ComboBox({editable: false, store:['STRING', 'NUMBER']})},
   ];


  var config = {
    columns: object_field_columns,
          store: store,
          plugins: [this.editor],
          //autoHeight: true,
          height: 200,
          tbar: [{
              text: 'Add',
              iconCls: 'silk-add',
              handler: this.onAdd,
              scope: this,
          }, '-', {
              text: 'Delete',
              iconCls: 'silk-delete',
              handler: this.onDelete,
              scope: this,
          }, '-'],
  }





   Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));


   myapp.object_field_grid.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);


  },
  onRender: function() {
        this.store.load();
        myapp.object_field_grid.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

Ext.reg('object_field_grid', myapp.object_field_grid); // register xtype
```

My GET/POST requests are being properly routed to my index/add methods inside my controller and I am able to easily retrieve the paramaters that I pass it in the request.

My problem is with the update functionality PUT request. The PUT request does get successfully routed to my edit method inside the controller.

This is what the request looks like in firebug

```
http://server.local/object_fields/20
JSON



data
Object { name="test7777777777", more...}


id
"18"
Source
{"id":"18","data":{"name":"test7777777777","id":"20"}}
```

Inside my edit method I'm not receiving my array that I passed through the PUT request.
When I dump $this->params inside my edit method this is what is in the array.

```
([id] => 20
[named] => Array
    (
    )

[pass] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20
    )

[controller] => object_fields
[action] => edit
[[method]] => PUT
[plugin] => 
[url] => Array
    (
        [ext] => html
        [url] => object_fields/20
    )

[form] => Array
    (
    )

[isAjax] => 1
)
```

How can I properly receive my array through the PUT request inside my edit method?

UPDATE:

I am able to retrieve my array using the following code inside the edit method

```
function edit($id){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    echo 'edit';

     $raw  = '';
        $httpContent = fopen('php://input', 'r');
        while ($kb = fread($httpContent, 1024)) {
            $raw .= $kb;
        }
        fclose($httpContent);
        $params = array();
        parse_str($raw, $params);

    print_r($params);

}
```

The question is now why does cakePHP not do this automaticly?

Answer (score 0):

put this in your app_controller.php:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    if (
        isset($this->RequestHandler) &&
        $this->RequestHandler->requestedWith('json') &&
        (
            $this->RequestHandler->isPost() ||
            $this->RequestHandler->isPut()
        )
    ) {

        $jsonData = json_decode(utf8_encode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input'))), true);

        if (is_array($jsonData)) {

            $this->data = $jsonData;
            unset($jsonData);

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Note that you may run into this problem with PUT requests though: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/855-irrevocably-reading-phpinput-in-requesthelpercomponentstartup#ticket-855-1